# Position winform in the bottom left corner of the screen

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am trying to position a form in the bottom left hand corner of the screen (on the start button) I have the following code that attempts to do this, but only takes into account the work area of the screen - so the form is positioned just above the start button:

```
int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left + this.Width;
int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
this.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

A demo / screen is below to further demonstrate what I am trying to do:

[image: [Demo Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mTjj.png)]

Comment: You cannot overlap the taskbar or the Start button.

Comment: If I installed your software and it positioned itself so that it intentionally hides my start button I would immediately uninstall it.

Comment: @Hans Passant See answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` properties and set `this.TopMost = true`. this works:

```
int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height;
this.Location = new Point(0, y);
this.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this does work, despite what everyone else says :)

Comment: +1 and also taskbar height added to code as in the picture was .

Answer (score 4):

The Working area usually excludes any task bar, docked windows and docked tool bars.
Using the `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` gives you the complete height and width of your screen.

A sample code is as follows :

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Rectangle r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Location = new Point(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - this.Height);
            this.TopMost = true;
        }
```

This most likely will show below the task bar as usually task bar is set to be on top by default. I remember there was an option to turn that option off in Windows XP, not sure though.

EDIT:

In windows XP you can make the taskbar go behind windows. Follow the link : [Always on top task bar](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/bc/bcs4p9.html)

As pointed by Ria, setting the `this.TopMost` to true works and is a better option.

Comment: I was looking for how to position the window on top of the start bar and your code for this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; was the piece I was missing...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.Location = new Point(0, 
                          workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
```

Comment: it's gonna go behind the taskbar

Answer (score 0):

The [Ria 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338287/359170) is correct but it didn't add the taskbar height.
If you want exactly what in the image shown , you should use this code :

```
int nTaskBarHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - 
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom;
Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.Location = new Point(0, workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height + nTaskBarHeight);
this.TopMost = true;
```